# Load activity from a string variable

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I am doing an app where I have questions displayed and I have stored the next question number in a database so the user can resume whenever they wanted.

My problem here is I fetch the next question number from the DB and append the number to a String variable so then `goNextQuestion` is equal to `Question#` (# being the number from the DB).

I then want to pass that variable, for example it is equal to `Question2`, to the new Intent function to load the activity associated with that question.

Here is the code from Home.class:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                        final String goQuestion = "Question" + lastQuestion";
                        startActivity(new Intent(Home.this, Class.forName(goQuestion)));
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }
});
```

The full Home.class can be viewed here: https://pastebin.com/6mbrBpQm

My expected result would be it wil load the same way as it would if I just passed `Question2.class` into the Intent. However, there is an error and the `catch` statement is always executed with the following error:

```
W/System.err: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Question2.class
        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:400)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:326)
        at uk.co.jrtevents.k_quiz.Home$1.onClick(Home.java:45)
W/System.err:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5610)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22265)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "Question2.class" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/uk.co.jrtevents.k_quiz-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/uk.co.jrtevents.k_quiz-1/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        ... 13 more
```

What would be the best way to resolve this?

Link to Question2.class: https://pastebin.com/5sdsc1Ec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try something like below.

if you use the **Simple** class name like **Step8CompletedActivity** then it will give the error.

```
var clazz =
Class.forName(Step8CompletedActivity::class.java.simpleName!!).kotlin as KClass<Activity>
```

below error will come

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.google.samples.motionlayoutcodelab.MainActivityKt.access$getData$p(MainActivity.kt:1)
    at com.google.samples.motionlayoutcodelab.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:114)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6662)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Step8CompletedActivity
    at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:400)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:326)
    at com.google.samples.motionlayoutcodelab.MainActivityKt.<clinit>(MainActivity.kt:39)
    at com.google.samples.motionlayoutcodelab.MainActivityKt.access$getData$p(MainActivity.kt:1)
```

**instead** of using the simple name only use **Canonical** name or **Full name with path**

```
var clazz =
Class.forName(Step8CompletedActivity::class.java.canonicalName!!).kotlin as KClass<Activity>
```

or using below will produce the same results.

```
 var clazz =
Class.forName("com.google.samples.motionlayoutcodelab.Step8CompletedActivity").kotlin as KClass<Activity>
```

Comment: That worked! Thank you!! I changed the `goQuestion` variable to `final String goQuestion = "uk.co.jrtevents.k_quiz.Question" + lastQuestion;`

Answer (score 0):

You don't have put `.class`

```
  final String goQuestion = "Question" + lastQuestion;
```

Try this

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    final String goQuestion = "Question" + lastQuestion;
                    startActivity(new Intent(Home.this, Class.forName(goQuestion)));
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Now getting this error: `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Question2`

Comment: do you have Question2Activity? @Julian

Comment: @Julian check new answer

Comment: Same error, updated my question with more code and modifications based off your current answer. See Home.class here: https://pastebin.com/6mbrBpQm